# Can there be more than one barre in a guitar chord?

Tags: guitar, chords

I'm making a computer program that graphically represents a chord from text like this

```
    (chord name = "F")
    (barre = "Fret 1 strings EB finger 1")

    oE---
    oB---
    oG-2-
    oD--3
    xA---
    xE---
```

and represents it somewhat like this:

[image]

Would there ever be a situation where more than one barre is in one chord?  I need to know if I should implement multiple barres.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course. If you look at jazz chords, you might even find 3 barres in one chord. Here is one example with 2 barres: B7 chord, formed from A7 shape.

[image: b7]

Comment: @Mark don't forget to account for [Cut Capos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capo#Partial_capo) =)

Comment: Oh man if I'm gonna make it I'd better make it good!  And free!

Comment: IMHO this chord is not a good example -- the first finger needs only to cover the 5th string and doesn't have to be a barre

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  One situation I can think of involves a 6/9 chord.  For example, a Bb 6/9 chord could be fingered with the second finger on the 6th string, 6th fret, the first finger barring strings 4 & 3 at the 5th fret and the third finger barring strings 2 & 1 at the 6th fret.

Comment: If you extend the first-finger barre to the fifth string, you can get a third in there, too.

Answer (score 3):

There is a technique from Ted Greene Chord Chemistry book (acknowledged to George van Eps) to fret to adjacent strings on the same fret with one finger. Although this isn't barre (You should use tip of Your finger) this applies to what You want to do. In pic you uploaded You mark barre just with fingerings number - so the output of both techniques will be exactly the same.

If You want to go advanced Ted Greene presents in his book chords when You fret two notes on adjacent strings and adjacent frets!! with one finger (i.e. 1st string 5th fret and 2nd string 6th fret - both with first finger). All the software to automatic chord diagrams generation will fail on such fingerings. (All the software i know already - i'm open to be suprised nicely :)

Answer (score 2):

I know a lot of guitarists use a "lazy Barre-B", where you fret a B-major with your index finger over all strings at the second fret, then your middle or ring over the top 4 strings on the fourth fret, and then muting the high E either with a slight lift of the ring finger or with your pinky. This is generally faster than a true A-form Barre B.